# WPF Ribbon Application Menu with subitems executes subitem AND parent callback

Tags: wpf, callback, ribbon

I'm using Microsoft's new WPF ribbon (October 2010 release) and I designed my application menu with a `RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem`. If the user clicks on the `RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem`, I want to open the program settings dialog. The subitems contain direct links to the various tab pages in the settings dialog and I want to open the settings dialog with the chosen page selected.

```
<ribbon:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem
  Header="Settings"
  x:Name="SettingsItem"
  Click="settingsClicked"
>
  <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem
    Header="Scanner Settings"
    x:Name="scannerSettingsItem"
    Click="scannerSettingsClicked"
  />
  <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem
    Header="Printer Settings"
    x:Name="printerSettingsItem"
    Click="printerSettingsClicked"
  />
</ribbon:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem>
```

My problem is that when the user clicks on eg. the "Scanner Settings" subitem, first the `scannerSettingsClicked()` callback is executed and then the `settingsClicked()` callback, causing the settings dialog to be shown a second time right after it has been closed.

The properties windows in Visual Studio's WPF designer also refuses to show the callback subscriptions unless remove either the parent item's callback or that of all the subitems, so I guess I must be doing something wrong.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: I "solved" this by measuring the time passed between scannerSettingsClicked() ending and settingsClicked() starting. If it's less than 500 ms, I assume it's the followup call and do nothing. Not great, but gets the job done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your subitem click events, set `e.Handled = true` to keep the event from bubbling back up to the parent item.